# Can I mysqldump an entire database while using where='condition' on individual tables?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, condition

I have used mysqldump to dump an entire database,

However, when I want to use `--where=condition"`, on individual tables, I have dumped individual tables

```
mysqldump  --where='condition' mydb table > table.sql
```

and then reconstructed the database table by table

```
 for i in *sql; do mysql newdb < i; done
```

Is it possible to use the where clause with mysqldump on specific tables when dumping an entire database?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to custom script each table

The `--where` option is designed to help mysqldump a single table

Here is a post I made back in August 15, 2011

[Is it possible to mysqldump a subset of a database required to reproduce a query?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4654/is-it-possible-to-mysqldump-a-subset-of-a-database-required-to-reproduce-a-query/4659#4659)

Here is an crazy example

Suppose the table is this in the myworld database:

```
CREATE TABLE data_for_world
(
    id int not auto_increment,
    continent varchar(16),
    primary key (id)
);
insert into data_world (continent)
values ('Asia'),('Africa'),('Eupore'),
('NorthAmerica'),('SouthAmerica'),
('Australia'),('Antarctica');
```

and you want to break it up into two dumps

- one with continents that start with A
- one with continents that do not start with A

You will need three files (one for the database schema, and two for the data)

```
mysqldump --no-data --database myworld > myworld_schema.sql
mysqldump --no-create-info myworld data_for_world --where="substr(continent,1,1)='A'" > data1.sql
mysqldump --no-create-info myworld data_for_world --where="substr(continent,1,1)<>'A'" > data2.sql
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, that post has been very useful. I never second-guessed it until I wanted to subset the entire database and only use a simple select on one of the tables. It seems easier to just dump/restore the whole database, and then delete from the restored database.