# Tool to export data with all relational data?

Tags: mysql, backup, migration, mysqldump, tools

Is there a tool to export data from selected rows in a table with all data stored in other tables in other tables linked by relational design?

The purpose is to ease migrations of bits of data between servers for adhoc migrations. I am looking specifically for a tool for MySQL InnoDB with defined foreign keys.

Comment: are you asking to export the relationships themselves or the related data? also, which rdbms?

Comment: @swasheck, sorry about that, updated the question for clarity

Comment: Having written a program that does this (for SQL Server), I can tell you it's not for the faint of heart -- I *strongly* recommend using 3rd-party software to do this if it's available.

Comment: ...Also make sure you have a way to reconcile the migrated data to ensure that everything migrated *correctly*.

Comment: Jailer claims to be able to do that: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jailer/ (I haven't used though)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Yeah Jailer looks like what I am looking for, I've had some early success, but there is some weird stuff like it creating tables in the database, I'm going to explore it, but it might be what  I need. You should make your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In reality, you could just script it yourself using [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html).

Here my posts using the [--where option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where) for `mysqldump`:

- `Aug 15, 2011` : [Is it possible to mysqldump a subset of a database required to reproduce a query?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4654/is-it-possible-to-mysqldump-a-subset-of-a-database-required-to-reproduce-a-query/4659#4659)
- `Mar 14, 2012` : [Can I mysqldump an entire database while using where='condition' on individual tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15029/can-i-mysqldump-an-entire-database-while-using-where-condition-on-individual-t/15031#15031)
- `Jul 15, 2013` : [Export just rows modified in last month (date defined by user)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46383/export-just-rows-modified-in-last-month-date-defined-by-user/46390#46390)

With a good review of your tables and some SQL elbow grease, you can script the dump for any table and its child records with the corresponding foreign key references.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Ultimately I ended writing some custom logic to do the serialization and deserialization of the objects. I think custom scripting is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This would be nigh impossible to accomplish in MySQL unless all tables had necessary FOREIGN KEY constraints defined (not guaranteed at all, considering MyISAM doesn't support them).

If all tables DID have the FK's, it would still be quite a task and I don't know of a tool that would export a subset.

I know Navicat will attempt to reverse engineer the relations, but I don't think it will dump a subset of the data.

Comment: To your first point, I am using InnoDB with defined relational constraints