# Export just rows modified in last month (date defined by user)

Tags: mysql, backup, mysql-5.5, mysqldump, row-modification-time

I'm asking if it's possible in MySQL to export just rows modified in a period of time for example in the past month, if it is possible, how?

Comment: please edit your question, provide additional data such as `show create table`.

Comment: @ArashMousavi is not for a particular table or tables is just a general question, just asking for info and if it's possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would depend on the table having a timestamp column.

[mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) has a [`--where`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where) option that you can define when dumping a specific table

## EXAMPLE

If you have a table called `mydb.mytab` defined as follows

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tm TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

You could specify the date range on that table as follows (for June 2013):

```
WHERE_CLAUSE="(tm >= '2013-06-01 00:00:00') AND"
WHERE_CLAUSE="${WHERE_CLAUSE} (tm < '2013-07-01 00:00:00')"
mysqldump -uroot -p mydb mytable --where="${WHERE_CLAUSE}"
```

This would be most helpful since timestamps can be updated automatically.

I wrote a post on `Aug 15, 2011` on how to use `--where` to dump a subset of data not based on a timestamp : [Is it possible to mysqldump a subset of a database required to reproduce a query?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4654/is-it-possible-to-mysqldump-a-subset-of-a-database-required-to-reproduce-a-query/4659#4659)

If you do not have a timestamp column in the desired tables, you are better of just keeping all binary logs generated during any given month.