# How to take a database dump for selective set of values in few tables?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

```
create table foo (id, val1, user_id,...)
create table bar (id, foo_id, val2, ...)
create table baz (id, bar_id, val3, ...)

select * from foo where user_id = 1;
select * from bar where id in (select id from foo where user_id = 1)
select * from baz where id in (for all the above foos)
```

How do I write a dump command which does the above?

Comment: Your best bet is to just use CTAS queries to make copies of the tables containing only the data you need, then dump them.

Comment: Jailer promises to be able to do that: http://jailer.sourceforge.net/home.htm although I have never used it.

Answer (score 3):

I posted an answer similar to this back on `Aug 15, 2011` : [Is it possible to mysqldump a subset of a database required to reproduce a query?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4654/is-it-possible-to-mysqldump-a-subset-of-a-database-required-to-reproduce-a-query/4659#4659)

You will have to employ the use of `--lock-tables`

From [**that post**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4654/is-it-possible-to-mysqldump-a-subset-of-a-database-required-to-reproduce-a-query/4659#4659), the OP wanted all data connected with this query

```
select table1.id, table1.level, table2.name, table2.level 
       from table1 join table2 on table1.id = table2.table1_id 
       join table3 on table3.id = table2.table3_id
       where table3.name in ('fee', 'fi', 'fo', 'fum');
```

I recommended doing these mysqldumps

```
mysqldump -u... -p... --where="name in ('fee','fi','fo','fum')" mydb table3 > table3.sql
mysqldump -u... -p... --lock-all-tables --where="table3_id in (select id from table3 where name in ('fee','fi','fo','fum'))" mydb table2 > table2.sql
mysqldump -u... -p... --lock-all-tables --where="id in (select table1_id from table2 where table3_id in (select id from table3 where name in ('fee','fi','fo','fum')))" mydb table1 > table1.sql
```

You then have to load them in a target DB server in reverse order:

```
mysql -u... -p... -D newdb < table1.sql
mysql -u... -p... -D newdb < table2.sql
mysql -u... -p... -D newdb < table3.sql
```

Now, **let's look at your queries**

```
select * from foo where user_id = 1;
select * from bar where id in (select id from foo where user_id = 1)
select * from baz where id in (for all the above foos)
```

You would dump as follows:

- dump foo where user_id=1
- dump bar where foo_id in (select id from foo where user_id = 1)
- dump baz where bar_id in (select id from bar where foo_id in (select id from foo where user_id = 1))

Here the dumps

```
WHERE_CLAUSE="user_id=1"
mysqldump -u... -p... --where="${WHERE_CLAUSE}" mydb foo > foo_subset.sql
WHERE_CLAUSE="foo_id in (select id from foo where user_id = 1)"
mysqldump -u... -p... --lock-all-tables --where="${WHERE_CLAUSE}" mydb bar > bar_subset.sql
WHERE_CLAUSE="bar_id in (select id from bar where foo_id in"
WHERE_CLAUSE="${WHERE_CLAUSE} (select id from foo where user_id = 1))"
mysqldump -u... -p... --lock-all-tables --where="${WHERE_CLAUSE}" mydb baz > baz_subset.sql
```

Here is the reload order

```
mysql -u... -p... -D newdb < baz_subset.sql
mysql -u... -p... -D newdb < bar_subset.sql
mysql -u... -p... -D newdb < foo_subset.sql
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 1):

You have --where option on mysqldump command :

```
mysqldump <your options> <your database> foo --where 'user_id = 1'
```

Max.

Comment: Note that if you use subquery (i didn't saw on my first read, sorry) you should LOCK your tables with option -x (mysqldump <your options> <your database> foo -x --where 'user_id = 1')