# Database Dump/Backup but only to specific records?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

This question is about MySQL Backup (or Dump) whereby i want to backup and store information from only information related to a person; **SchoolA** from the **School Table** in this example.

So, I should not be able to see any information from other schools using that backup.

I want to give this backup information to that school. However, i do not want them to see information from other schools.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Do you want a specific student or just all students from schoolA ???

Comment: Information in Tags table from all students in a School.

Comment: What exact data are you dumping ???

Comment: Please tell us what operating system you are using : Windows or Linux ???

Comment: Just the records themselves are important, it's like an attendance system. I am using a Ubuntu MySQL database where i've information being fed in while a PHP application displays information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would dump each table using the [**--where**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where) option. I wrote a rather gnarly post about 4 years ago : [Is it possible to mysqldump a subset of a database required to reproduce a query?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4654/is-it-possible-to-mysqldump-a-subset-of-a-database-required-to-reproduce-a-query/4659#4659)

In your case, you can do the following: Suppose the database is called schooldb

## Dump by SchoolID

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
OPTS="--lock-all-tables"
SCHOOLID=1
WHERE="tagID in (select tagID from Ownership where studentID in"
WHERE="${WHERE} (select studentID from Students where schoolID = ${SCHOOLID}))"
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${OPTS} --where="${WHERE}" schooldb tags > tags.sql
```

## Dump by School Name

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
OPTS="--lock-all-tables"
SCHOOL_NAME=schoolA
WHERE="tagID in (select tagID from Ownership where studentID in"
WHERE="${WHERE} (select studentID from Students where schoolID in"
WHERE="${WHERE} (select schoolID from Schools where name='${SCHOOL_NAME}')))"
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${OPTS} --where="${WHERE}" schooldb tags > tags.sql
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

If you are using mysql client only, you could dumping [**SELECT ... INTO**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html)

```
SELECT B.studentID,B.name,D.tagID,D.data
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM Schools A
INNER JOIN Students  B ON A.SchoolID  = B.SchoolID
INNER JOIN Ownership C ON B.studentID = C.studentID
INNER JOIN Tags      D ON C.tagID     = D.tagID
WHERE A.name = 'schoolA';
```

or

```
SELECT B.studentID,B.name,D.tagID,D.data
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM Schools A
INNER JOIN Students  B ON A.schoolID  = B.schoolID
INNER JOIN Ownership C ON B.studentID = C.studentID
INNER JOIN Tags      D ON C.tagID     = D.tagID
WHERE A.schoolID = 1;
```

Comment: I'm not used to this method as i'm rather new to the database programming however is there a MySQL version scripting example or how do i try this script?

Comment: Weirdly i'm having "Error Code: 1. Can't create/write to file '/var/www/html/result.csv' (Errcode: 13) 0.015 sec" even though i'm using root@% with full rights..

Comment: This means your `/tmp` partition has run out of space and the file can't be created, or for whatever reason the `mysqld` process cannot write to that directory because of permission problems. Sometimes this is the case when `selinux` rains on your parade.

Any operation that requites a "temp file" will go into the `/tmp` directory by default. The name you're seeing is just some internal random name.

Comment: The /tmp example in my answer was cut-and-pasted from the Documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html). You are right it is permissions. You would have to play games with the secure_file_priv option or you could run mysqld as root to get around such restrictions.