# How to mysqldump to a subset of rows in specific table during a complete backup

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I have a database (myDB) that holds some tables. During my backup process I have one of those tables that should be filtered. So I want to backup only a subset of rows inside table1, when I backup the entire database.

I am using mysqldump like this:

```
mysqldump -uUSER -pPASSWORD --routines --add-drop-database   --databases myDB --tables table1 -w "id<3"> myDB_BK.sql
```

The subset rows is correct for table1 but I dont have the entire database. Only the specified table1.

I've tried all combination with no success.

Any Idea in how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dumping subsets of table data can only be done backing up individual tables.

I once answered a post entitled [Is it possible to mysqldump a subset of a database required to reproduce a query?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4654/is-it-possible-to-mysqldump-a-subset-of-a-database-required-to-reproduce-a-query/4659#4659). In that post, I used mysqldump strictly against the tables in question.

The only thing you can do is to produce two dumps

- mysqldump of the database without `table1` (means you have to name all other tables (See my old post [How do you mysqldump specific table(s)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9306/how-do-you-mysqldump-specific-tables/9309#9309))
- mysqldump only `table1` using `-w` or `--where`
- concatenate the second dump to the first dump

**Give it a Try !!!**