# How to restore one mysql database with mysqldump

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, windows-10

to make a backup I run:

```
mysqldump --host=localhost --user=root --password=whatever --single-transaction --routines --triggers --log-error=error.txt mydatabase > out.sql
```

Is it possible to do the same in reverse (restore out.sql) with mysqldump?

in case it is not possible, what is the most recommended command to import the database out.sql, in the same conditions in which it was exported by mysqldump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) to reload a database dump. You reload with the [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/programs-client.html) client.

See my old post [Is it possible to mysqldump a subset of a database required to reproduce a query?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4654/is-it-possible-to-mysqldump-a-subset-of-a-database-required-to-reproduce-a-query/4659#4659) for example. I perform 3 mysqldumps and then reload the dumps using the mysql client.

for your mysqldump in the question, it would be (in simplified terms)

```
mysql -u user -p < out.sql
```

If the dump file has multiple databases, then it would be

```
mysql -u user -p --one-database mydatabase < out.sql
```

See mysql option [--one-database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_one-database) for more info.

### UPDATE 2021-08-21 17:33 EDT

Your command

```
mysqldump --host=localhost --user=root --password=whatever --single-transaction --routines --triggers --log-error=error.txt mydatabase > out.sql
```

does not set the target database. You have to tell the mysql client.

```
mysql --host=anotherhost --user=root --password=whatever -Dtargetdatabase < out.sql
```

If you want to put the target database inside the dump, do this

```
mysqldump --host=localhost --user=root --password=whatever --single-transaction --routines --triggers --log-error=error.txt --databases mydatabase > out.sql
```

Then, the mysql client will be told what the target is

```
mysql --host=anotherhost --user=root --password=whatever < out.sql
```

because the line

```
USE mydatabase;
```

will appear just before the first table is made and loaded.

Comment: Please refresh your page. I updated my answer.

Comment: could I put the full mysql command, simulating the same dump export conditions? Thanks in advance

Comment: You would need to pipe the output of the mysqldump straight to mysql.

Comment: It would something like '`mysqldump -haddr1 -uroot1 -ppassword1... | mysql -haddr2 -uroot2 -ppassword2`

Comment: the command i use is the one i posted. What I want is to make sure that when I run your command, the database remains the same as when it was exported. forgive me but I'm nerbie

Comment: Posted an update. Go away from work for the day ....

Comment: super great explanation. thanks

Comment: related question https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/298565/how-can-i-create-a-mysql-database-if-it-doesnt-exist-or-drop-it-if-it-exists